# Search for item in a list of tuples

Tags: list, python-3.x, tuples

I have a list of tuples structured as per the below (data is example only):

```
[('aaa', 10), ('bbb', 10), ('ccc', 12), ('ddd', 12), ('eee', 14)]
```

I need to search the second item in each of the tuples (the number) to see if it exists in the list (eg search for 12 = found, search for 5 = not found.

Currently I am using the below, which works but may not be the best way in Python:

```
not_there = True
for a in final_set:
    if final_set[1] == episode_id:
        not_there = False
        break
```

What is the best / most efficient way in Python to do this?

Comment: you can do `episode_id in [a for _, a in final_set]`, or `any(a == episode_id for _, a in final_set)` (also the code you wrote does not work because you compare `final_set[1]` instead of `a[1]`)

Comment: Yes, thank you I just saw that after I posted it  :).  I will try your suggestion out thank you.

Comment: Hi again, does that code work regardless of whether I'm searching element 1 in the tuple (the 'aaa') or element 2 (the number)?

Comment: of course not, since it compares the second element of each tuple with the episode id.

Comment: I'm sorry njzk2, but clearly I'm not following your answer.  Can you explain how this works as I can't see where "episode_id in [a for _, a in final_set]" indicates that it's using the second element in the tuple....  I'm still learning Python and can't understand this statement?  thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at what `[a for _, a in final_set]` outputs. it should give you a sense of what is happening. Which is called "unpacking". And `_` is a common name for an unused variable.

Comment: Ok will do - appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this :

```
test = [('aaa', 10), ('bbb', 10), ('ccc', 12), ('ddd', 12), ('eee', 14)]
number = 10

for i in test:
  if number in i:
    print("Number {} found.".format(number))
  else:
    print("Number {} not found".format(number))
```

That should work regardless you're searching element 1 in the tuple (the 'aaa') or element 2 (the number).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Boky - i tried this and it does work, but I am trying to target the search for a particular element in the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

`is_there = (len([item for item in final_set if item[1] == episode_id]) > 0)`

Basically, `[item for item in final_set if item[1] == episode_id]` is a list comprehension expression which creates a list of the items in `final_set` such that `item[1] == episode_id`.

Then, you can check the length of the resulting list: if it is greater than 0, than something has been found.